# Should I use 'for testing' or 'to test'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have to write one of the following phrases into a formal mail

> 1. I would like to know if you can provide an adaptor for the (name of the equipment) *for testing* these two type of sensors :
> 2. I would like to know if you can provide an adaptor for the (name of the equipment) *to test* these two type of sensors :

Should I use 'for testing' or 'to test'?

Comment: 'adaptator' -> probably 'adaptor' or 'adapter'

Comment: I would use "... for *the testing of* these two type of sensors"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both will be understood, neither seems problematic.

To be be really picky, unless the adaptor itself does the testing (and I guess it does not) **to test** is not quite the right flavour. **for testing** has a more indirect feeling, so I think is slightly better. However I would probably be more explicit

> ... an adaptor that will enable testing of these two types of sensors.